# In Laravel 5, where do I store my php script that my XMLHttpRequest() calls?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have a page that contains the following:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
   //do something
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "api.php, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Where should I store my api.php file within Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you need to declare routes, for example:

```
Route::get('api/users', 'UserController@index');
```

So,you can use the route `api/users` for example:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "api/users", true);
```

In this case, you need to create the `UserController` in your `app/http/controllers` folder, for example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class UserController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

According to the following route `Route::get('api/users', 'UserController@index');`, the `index` method in `UserController` will be invoked whenever you send a request to the following url: `http://example.com/api/users`.

Btw, the route declaration should go into the `app/http/routes.php` file and you must read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2) to learn more about `Laravel`.

Comment: How would you do this for an ajax call to a non-Laravel php api on a different server?
EG, 
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://someServer/api.php, true);